# Change OpenVPN options with Network Manager (16.04-DT)

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I used a setup script from my VPN provider (PrivateInternetAccess.com) to configure the VPN settings in Network Manager. Problem is that my ISP drops the connection once a day and then assigns a new IP. OpenVPN doesn't reconnect automatically when that happens. I checked the docs and managed to set `--ping` and `--ping-restart` in VPN / Advanced. Now it recognizes that the link is down but fails with

`syslog.1.tmp:May 30 04:40:03 myHost nm-openvpn[1117]: RESOLVE: Cannot resolve host address: germany.privateinternetaccess.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Looks like OpenVPN tries to reconnect while the (dead) TUN interface is still active. It turns out that the setup script set the `--persist-tun` parameter and I think that might be a problem. Can anybody tell me how to disable that?

Comment: I would still be interested in a solution to this problem. In my case, it is not a GUI-based server, but a desktop that needs to be permanently connected to our VPN.

Comment: Seems this bug report is relevant: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767737 (also see linked issue here: https://github.com/flamusdiu/python-pia/issues/8)

Comment: Even on a desktop you can still use the openvpn daemon and configure it through /etc/openvpn/yourserver.conf. Network Manager is maybe nice for dynamic situations like a laptop connecting to different WiFi networks. But if you have a desktop which _always_ needs to be connected to the VPN i wouldn't recommend it. Also your linked post (though quite old) contains the words "systematically fail at all possible levels" which is probably not a good sign. In that case: Go static all the way...

Comment: By desktop I meant "not server", actually these are laptops, which I want to be connected to our VPN whenever they have a working internet connection, be it wired or wireless. But anyway, until the NetworkManager bug is fixed, I will have to use some scripts to connect.

Comment: I seem to remember that OpenVPN integration in NM is optional. If that's the case just use the daemon and a .conf file with the parameters from the question and it will reconnect as soon as there's internet connectivity. To force VPN you can then use an (also static) firewall ruleset which allows only DHCP and VPN on eth0 and allows everything on tun0. There should be no need for scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems like running a GUI-based server was a bad idea. Forget about the question, I'll try my luck on the commandline.

Comment: CLI rocks, screw Network Manager ;)